# Научить docker контейнер получать интернет через socks proxy

Tags: proxy, docker, socks5

Приветствую вас, умы.

Есть сервер, на котором закрыт доступ к сети (адресам) в рамках хостера. Есть docker контейнер с приложением, которому надо ходить на эти адреса.
Решение, которое мне пришло в голову - поднять tor и заворачивать приложения через него, в рамках socks прокси.

Вопрос, как запустить docker контейнер через этот прокси?

заранее благодарю за ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Dockerfile можно указать

```
ENV HTTP_PROXY socks5://host:5000
```

Аналогичные переменные окружения есть для HTTPS и FTP. Если не будет работать попробуйте http_proxy в нижнем регистре.